# Disable jQuery mobile button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to disable this button

```
<a  data-role="button" id="next"  data-icon="arrow-r" >Next</a>
```

The click event should not fire and the button UI should also reflect a button disabled state.

I have tried the following

```
$("#next").attr('disabled',true);
$("#next").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#next").button('disable');
$("#next").button().button('disable');
```

None seems to deal with the 2 issues at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YFMsR/

Unfortunately only INPUT button can be disabled with **`button('disable')`** so you will need to simulate it like this:

```
$('#next').prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-disabled');
```

Class **`ui-disabled`** is a jQuery Mobile class used for disabled look.

Full example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    // So we can test if button is disabled or not
    $(document).on('click', '#next', function(){     
        alert('Click event');
    });    
    $('#next').prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-disabled');
});
```

If you want to find out more then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/enable-disable-jquery-mobile-button/)**, you will find this topic described in much more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable `<a>` per se.

You can:

- Cancel the navigation with `return false;`
- set the `href` to `#`.
- Use `<input type="button">` instead.

---

If you are using jQuery ui's button widget, you should use this:

```
$( "#next" ).button( "disable" );
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-disable)

Comment: Using the <input type="button"> works, the event doesnt fire but the UI of the button is not updated to a disabled state

Comment: @KehindeKolexinfosKolade, using `$('the-selector').attr('disabled', 'disabled')` will do that.

Comment: No it does not button the button UI in a disabled state

Comment: @KehindeKolexinfosKolade, We need more context to know what's going on in your page, set a jsFiddle and edit your question, someone will help you, I need to leave the computer for couple of  hours, gl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It disable navigation

```
   $("button class").attr("disabled", "disabled");

   $('button class').css('opacity', '0.3');
```