# How to call function on page load in jquery mobile and how to pass data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

[image]I am using jquery mobile. I want to call function on page load. I  googled a lot find using

But it did not work.
I also need to pass data from one page to another in jquery mobile. Here is my code:
I need to call loadData function on page load so that table view is created.
How to pass data from one page to another?
i see like this.[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <title></title>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css">
        <ink rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css">

        <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->


        <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
        <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

        <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->


    </head>
    <style>

        .ui-page {

            background : transparent
            url(img/Background-Screen.png)
            no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
             -o-background-size :100% 100%;

            background-size : cover;
        }
        #CaseInformationScreen {

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;
            background-size : cover;
        }


        #UserSettingScreen {

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;
            background-size : cover;
        }


    </style>



    <body>


        <!--page one My Cases Screen------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Cases</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                    <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                    <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog"id="Edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
                </ul>
                <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>Case Information</h1>
                        <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Add</a>
                    </div>
                      <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                            </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Case Date:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                            </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>



                  <div data-role="popup" id="UserSettingScreen" data-close-btn="none">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="CancelSettingButton">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>User Settings</h1>
                        <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
                    </div>
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">IP Address:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                    </div>  
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                            <option value="standard">A</option>
                            <option value="rush">B</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                 </div>

              </div>

             <script>

                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function(){ 
                    console.log("init");
                    test();
                });

                function test() {
                    alert("dfg")
                    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                        $('#folderData').append(
                            '<li class="row" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>Broken Bells</h2>' + '<p>Broken Bells</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + '</li>'
                        );
                    }

                }

        </script>
            </div>




        <!-- Page two  Case Information Screen-------------------------->  




        <!-- Page Three  Case User setting Screens-------------------------->  



        <!-- Page Four  Document Information Screens-------------------------->  
        <div data-role="page" >
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false">Cancel</a>
                <h1>Document Information</h1>
                <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Name:</label>
                <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
            </div>  
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Date:</label>
                <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textarea-12">Notes:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!------------------------------>
     <div data-role="page" id="DocumentScreen" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Documents</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <div><img src="img/Connect-Realtime.png"/></div>
                    <!--a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a-->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderInside_Data" >
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>



    </body>


    <script >

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // $('.ui-loader').remove();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');


        });
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                       //  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
                         $(document).delegate('.ui-content', 'touchmove', false);
                         });







        $(".row").click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"), {                      
            transition: "slide",
               reverse: false,
            changeHash: false         
        });
                        console.log(this.id)
                        });
// $('#here_table').append(content);
        $("#addbuttons").on("click", "a", function() {

            if ($(this).attr("id") == "Add") {
                           // alert("--")
                        //    alert("---")
                          //  console.log('divclicked');
                        //    $('#CaseInformationScreen').popup();
                          //  $('#CaseInformationScreen').popup('open');

                          // $.mobile.changePage('#popupStatus','pop',true,true);
               /*$.mobile.changePage($("#CaseInformationScreen"), {
                    transition: "slidedown",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: false,
                    role: 'dialog',

                });*/
            } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Setting") {

            } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Edit") {

            }
        });

      $("#Cancel").click(function() {
                        // alert("---")
                         $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')
                        // ('#CaseInformationScreen').dialog('close');
      $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                    transition: "pop",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: false
                });

});
      $("#CancelSettingButton").click(function() {

       $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                    transition: "slide",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: false
                });

});

/*function createDir(dirname){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSys) {
                fileSys.root.getDirectory(dirname, {create: true,
exclusive: false},
                    function(directory) {
                        console.log("Directory has been created");
                    }, createError);
            }, createError);
}

function createError(error){
       alert(error.code);
}

<!-------------------->

You have to get a directoryentry (the variable entry in the examples) 
first. This can be done in two ways: 
way 1: getLocalFileSystem 

function onSuccess(fileSystem) { 
    var entry=fileSystem.root; 
} 

// request the persistent file system 
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, 
onError); 

or  way 2: resolveLocalFileSystemURI 

function onSuccess(directryEntry) { 
    var entry = directoryEntry; 
} 

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///sdcard", onSuccess, 
onError); */
<!------------------------------------------>



<!------------------------------------------------------>
/*var reader;
    var text;
    var myFileSystem;

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function myfile() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotmyFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        myFileSystem = fileSystem;
        console.log(fileSystem.name);
    }

    function gotmyFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme2.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
            console.log(file);
            text = evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function readmyfile() {
        var myPara = document.getElementById("mytext");
        myPara.innerText = text;
    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }*/


    <!----------------------------Example-------------------->

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
      }

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
          console.log(fileSystem.name);
          var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
          directoryEntry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
      }

      function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
          console.log(parent);
         // alert(parent+"Directory");
      }

      function onDirectoryFail(error) {
          alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
      }

      function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.error.code);
          alert(evt.target.error.code);
      }

    </script>




</html>

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgfL6.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper way to initialize function on a page load is:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/

Regarding passing data from one page to another, there are several solutions, you can find them in my blog  **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**. Just search for the chapter called: **Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions**. You will also find working examples.

Basically there are 3 main approaches:

1. Pass data from page 1 to page 2 directly. It requires several **`HTML`** pages, it will not work with one **`HTML`** containing several pages.
2. Store data into some global javascript variable (the easiest solution).
3. Store data into **`localstorage`**

**EDIT :**

There's one more thing. If you are using several **`HTML`** pages you need to be careful with your javascript. When jQuery Mobile loads additional **`HTML`** pages it loads only **`BODY`** content so everything inside a **`HEAD`** will be discarded. Solutions to this problem can be fond **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.

**EDIT 2 :**

You had an error in your example. You were missing **`BODY`** tag. And you had 2 much initialized css files. Only 1 is needed.

Here is a working example:

**index.html:** - This is just a test page so we can try to go from page 1 to page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Packer Forbes Communications</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="index" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="test.html">click me</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.html** - And this is your fixed page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <title></title>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Cases</h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog"id="Edit">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folder_Contend_Data" >
            </ul>
            <!--- CaseInformationScreen Popup screen---------------------------->
            <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Add</a>
                </div>
                <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Case Date:</label>
                    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--- CaseInformationScreen Popup screen End---------------------------->

            <!--- User Setting Popup screen---------------------------->
            <div data-role="popup" id="UserSettingScreen" data-close-btn="none">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="CancelSettingButton">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>User Settings</h1>
                    <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
                </div>
                <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">IP Address:</label>
                    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
                </div>  
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                        <option value="standard">A</option>
                        <option value="rush">B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--- User Setting Popup screen End---------------------------->

        </div>
        <script>

                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function(){ 
                    console.log("init");
                    test();
                });

                function test() {
                    alert("dfg")
                    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                        $('#folder_Contend_Data').append(
                            '<li class="row" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>Broken Bells</h2>' + '<p>Broken Bells</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + '</li>'
                        );
                    }
                                            $('#folder_Contend_Data').listview('refresh');

                }

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But facing the same problem .Function is call but list view is not display.

Comment: Here is my code i want to call test function so that i am able to make dynamic list

Comment: Dont use document ready (if this is your current code) and put your SCRIPT block inside a page DIV. It is not enough to put it behind a closed BODY tag.

Comment: Basically go to this link http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/ and carefully read SOLUTION 1.

Comment: I also use like that But same effect ..can you please modify this?

Comment: if test.html is my first page ? then what hapen?

Comment: How is it not working. If my examples are working so should yours.

Comment: alert is display but list is display as actual..:(

Comment: Use $('#folder_Contend_Data').listview('refresh'); after for loop. All dynamically added content must be manually enhanced. I have an article about that: http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/

Comment: I have also add it in my example so take a look.

Comment: yes but what about the row click event ? then it is not firing

Comment: $(".row").click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"), {                      
            transition: "slide",
               reverse: false,
            changeHash: false         
        });
                        console.log(this.id)
                        });

Comment: Don't bind your click event like that. you should have read my first article, everything is described there. When binding events in jQuery Mobile you MUST use delegated binding. It dont care if element is available in DOM or not.

Comment: Do it like this: $(document).on('click', '#elementID', function(){ });

Comment: And remember, jQuery Mobile is not classic web development.

Comment: I am facing more issue ..When i click setting or add Button it show pop up (in between i again click it is hide) Example if i click add button it show dialog then again i click setting button intend of showing setting popup it hide the first .I think whenever there is pop up screen it will disble all three buttons ? how to disable button while showing pop up.

Comment: Secondly whenever there is popup screen display .then user also able to scroll table view so pop up screen also scroll then it will also hiden.May be user not able to scroll if there is pop upscreen display.Here is my update code..jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/9

Comment: I didn't understand you correctly. But let me give you few advices. Use popup only as a massage/warning display or for simple forms. If you need to show a complex form then use DIALOG. Dialog is not same thing as popup. Also here's my other answer where you can find out how to disable the button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855418/disable-jquery-mobile-button/16856138#16856138

Comment: If you want anything more please open another question because your current problems don't have anything to do with this question.